# Salvar dados em um arquivo de texto para ler posteriormente

Tags: c#, arquivo

Gostaria de saber como que eu salvo alguns dados como exemplo, no caso números, em um arquivo de texto de forma que quando eu fechar o aplicativo os dados ainda estarão salvos e quando eu abri-los poderei retomá-los.

Comment: Como estão os dados. O que deseja fazer com eles?

Comment: Estao em modo de texto (string) e em numeros (double) no caso e um sistema de poupanca que estou querendo fazer obrigado.

Comment: Isto ajuda pouco mas parece que você já está satisfeito. Se você tivesse colocado mais detalhes eu faria um exemplo para você quer o jeito certo de fazer. Mas sem informações detalhadas, não consigo ajudar mais.

Comment: Tudo tranquilo cara ja deu certinho kkk obrigado pela ajuda !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A estratégia que vai querer usar é algo bem simples: escrever a um arquivo os dados, e ao re-abrir o app, lê os mesmos dados e põe-os no lugar certo.

C# (e o framework .NET) disponibiliza a classe `File` por exatamente esse caso. Mais documentação se encontra [nesse link do microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Obrigado me ajudou bastante !

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro você pesquisar por arquivos XML, nele você pode organizar os dados a partir de "tags" e depois lê-los. Dê uma olhada na classe System.Xml